# 2D vector multiplication

Tags: c++, vector, multiplication

my problem is that when i try to multiply a 2D vector by another 2D vector and store the result of the process in another 2D vector my programme crash

```
    int main()
{

    vector< vector<double> > Mat_1;
    vector< vector<double> > Mat_2;
    vector< vector<double> > Mat_3;
// Generate 2D vector 5 by 5 
    setVector(Mat_1,5,5);
    setVector(Mat_2,5,5);

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            Mat_3[i][j] = 0;

            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            {
                Mat_3[i][j] += Mat_1[i][k] * Mat_2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the dimensions of `Mat_3`?

Comment: "Crash" is not a problem description. Use a debugger to dig into an issue.

Comment: didn't set it, should i ?

Comment: Yes.Otherwise you get an index out of bound exception when you try to access the values.

Comment: Okey , i'll try to define the dimensions :) , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize the 3rd matrix, and you are doing indexing operations on it, that's Undefined Behaviour. You can do this....

```
void init_2Dvector(vector<vector<double> >& vec, int x_dim, int y_dim){
    vec.resize(x_dim);
    for(int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++)
         vec[i].resize(y_dim);
}

int main()
{

    vector< vector<double> > Mat_1;
    vector< vector<double> > Mat_2;
    vector< vector<double> > Mat_3;
// Generate 2D vector 5 by 5 
    setVector(Mat_1,5,5);
    setVector(Mat_2,5,5);

// Set dimension for result
    init_2Dvector(Mat_3, 5, 5);

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            Mat_3[i][j] = 0;

            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            {
                Mat_3[i][j] += Mat_1[i][k] * Mat_2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vote is now in the other direction :)

Comment: Not getting the exact result !

Comment: @Rafikox05, what exact results are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

This line will cause problemS:

```
    Mat_3[i][j] = 0;
```

Since you (atleast from the code you showed) never initialize Mat_3, try adding:

```
setVector(Mat_3,5,5);
```

Comment: setVector() will initialize a vector with random values :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `Mat_3`.  So make sure to set its dimensions same as you did with other Matrices.

This should work once you include proper libraries and **do not** use `using namespace std;`

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Mat_1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Mat_2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Mat_3;
    setVector(Mat_1,5,5);
    setVector(Mat_2,5,5);
    setVector(Mat_3,5,5); // here initialize 

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            Mat_3[i][j] = 0; // here assigning zeros

            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            {
                Mat_3[i][j] += Mat_1[i][k] * Mat_2[k][j]; // operation
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works even if input matrices are different dimensions, e.g., 3x2 and 2x4.

```
vector<vector<double>> multiply_2d_vectors(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & v1, std::vector<std::vector<double>> & v2)
{
    int v1_row = v1.size();
    int v1_col = v1[0].size();
    int v2_row = v2.size();
    int v2_col = v2[0].size();
    // v1_col must be equal to v2_row

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v3;
    setVector(v3,v1_row,v2_col);

    for(int i=0; i < v1_row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j < v2_col;j++)
        {
            v3[i][j] = 0;

            for(int k=0; k < v1_col; k++)
            {
                v3[i][j] += v1[i][k] * v2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return v3;
}
```